# SWT to BMML representation

Tags: swt, balsamiq

I was trying to convert a dialog built in SWT into BMML. Can any one help in how can I achieve it

Answer (score 0):

Here's the [blog post](http://in.relation.to/Bloggers/InstantMockupForEclipseSWTApplications) and the [source repository](http://github.com/maxandersen/update.xam.dk/tree/master) for the SWT to BMML plugin.

Answer (score -1):

Here's some code that does the conversion from SWT to WireframeSketcher's screen format:
http://pastebin.com/f4625affc

This code is actually used by WireframeSketcher for it's Spy plugin. For more details see this blog post: [SWT to Mockup: WireframeSketcher Spy plugin](http://wireframesketcher.com/blog/2009-06-04-swt-to-mockup-wireframesketcher-spy-plugin.html)